# Mongoose And mongodb findById with object in object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i want make a vote app,i have a schema called Poll.
in the Poll schema i have a "options" object.
i want to update the options.vote by id.
how i call to Poll(id).options(id).vote?
that my try:

```
app.post("/:id/:option_id", function(req, res){
    Poll.findById(req.params.id,function(err, poll){
       if(err){
           console.log("Vote(find the Poll) post err");
       } else{
            poll.options.findById(req.params.option_id,function(err,option){
               if(err){
                   console.log("Vote(find the option) post err");
               } else{
               option.vote++;
               option.vote.save(function(err){
                  if(err){
                   console.log("save vote error");
               } else{
                   res.redirect("/:id/:option_id");
               } 
               });
           }});
       }
```

Comment: You want `.findOne()` as `.findById()` is "strictly" an aliased shortcut for `.findOne({ "_id": id })`. That's all it's for. You want something else, then you use the full method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `poll.options.findById` as it is mongoose function and poll which you get inside of callback and `poll.option` is not a Poll schema object. What you may try to do is: I am assuming here that options is an array having a field of Id and one of vote. So you may try as:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

Poll.findById(req.params.id,function(err, poll){
   if(err){
       console.log("Vote(find the Poll) post err");
   } else{
       var options = poll.options;
       var optionIndex = _.findIndex(options,["id", req.params.option_id])
       poll.options[optionIndex].vote ++;
       poll.save(function(err)){
            if(err){
               console.log("save vote error");
           } else{
               res.redirect("/:id/:option_id");
           } 

       }
   }
});
```

**EDIT**: 
[Lodash](https://lodash.com) a simple library that has some array manipulation methods written for usage.

Comment: thank you, so first you find by id the Poll,after find the index of option increase the vote, and save. and my question :what its "lodash"(its giving me a error "Cannot find module 'lodash'"). i google it and little not understand

Comment: You need to install lodash module by running command npm install lodash --save @NaorMalca. Check the Edited answer for more info